# SQLite doesn't insert values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I don't know why, but when I log in into my app it doesn't create the values in the SQLite database

this is my code:

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "nome";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_DATA_NASCIMENTO = "data_nascimento";
    private static final String KEY_DATA_CRIADO = "user_datacriado";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATA_CRIADO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String nome, String email, String uid, String data_nascimento, String user_datacriado) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, nome); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_DATA_NASCIMENTO, data_nascimento); // Created At
        values.put(KEY_DATA_CRIADO, user_datacriado); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("nome", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_USERS, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }
}
```

This is in the login fragment:

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("nome");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String data_nascimento = user.getString("data_nascimento");
                        String user_datacriado = user.getString("user_datacriado");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, data_nascimento, user_datacriado);
                        // Launch main activity
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                //MainActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(intent);
                        //finish();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                getActivity(),
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
...
```

While debugging, the `adduser(...)` method:

```
long id = db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
```

`id` is always **-1** and I don't know why.

Comment: No column avalaible in table with `KEY_DATA_NASCIMENTO` name then why using `values.put(KEY_DATA_NASCIMENTO, data_nascimento);` line?

Comment: I am not sure check this KEY_ID is primary key where you are inserting it?

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` to get a useful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your `CREATE TABLE` is missing the SQL for the `data_nascimento` column you're trying to insert values into.

After adding it, you can uninstall your app to recreate the database.

Comment: Thanks alot. Yesterday i locked at it and i knew I was going to forget about it :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to [Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) to `Id` `PRIMARY KEY` column.